# How to pivot_wider only a single condition using a single command in R

Tags: r, dataframe

Let's say I test 3 drugs (A, B, C) at 3 conditions (0, 1, 2), and then I want to compare two of the conditions (1, 2) to a reference condition (0). This is the plot I would like to get:

[image]

First: I do get there, but my solution seems overly complex.

```
# The data I have
df <- data.frame(
    drug = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C"),
    cond = c(0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2),
    result = c(1, 2, 3, 2, 4, 6, 3, 6, 9),
)
# The data I want
df_wider0 <- data.frame(
    drug = c("A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C"),
    result0 = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3),
    cond = c(1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2),
    result = c(2, 3, 4, 6, 6, 9)
)
# This pivots also condition 1 and 2 ...
df_wider <- tidyr::pivot_wider(
    df,
    names_from = cond,
    values_from = result
)
# ... so I pivot out these two again ...
colnames(df_wider)[colnames(df_wider) == "0"] <- "result0"
df_wider0 <- tidyr::pivot_longer(
    df_wider,
    cols = c("1", "2"),
    names_to = "cond",
    values_to = "result"
)
# ... so that I can use this ggplot command:
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df_wider0, aes(x = result0, y = result, label = drug)) +
    geom_label() +
    facet_wrap("cond")
```

As you can see, I use a sequence of `pivot_wider` and `pivot_longer` to do a selective `pivot_wider` (by inverting some of its effects later). Is there an integrated command that I can use to achieve this more elegantly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can also be a strategy.  (Will work even if there are unequal number of conditions per group)

```
df %>%
  filter(cond != 0) %>%
  right_join(df %>% filter(cond == 0), by = "drug", suffix = c("", "0")) %>%
  select(-cond0)
```

Revised `df` adopted

```
df <- data.frame(
  drug = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C", "D"),
  cond = c(0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0),
  result = c(1, 2, 3, 2, 4, 6, 3, 6, 9, 10)
)
```

Result of above syntax

```
  drug cond result result0
1    A    1      2       1
2    A    2      3       1
3    B    1      4       2
4    B    2      6       2
5    C    1      6       3
6    C    2      9       3
7    D   NA     NA      10
```

You may also fill `cond` if desired so

Comment: Thanks! I accepted this answer over the other one since this one is easier to extend to multiple identifier (`drug`) columns.

Comment: For less heavy R users, a version of this without `%>%` is `df_wider0 <- dplyr::right_join(dplyr::filter(df, cond != 0), dplyr::filter(df, cond == 0), by = "drug", suffix = c("", "0"))` (break across lines as needed).

Comment: Any particular reason you chose `right_join` over the alternatives (`left_join`, `inner_join`, `full_join`)? Since only non-NA rows are plotted, it should not make any difference to the plot.

Comment: Yes, if plotting is the ultimate objective, it won't make a difference then

Answer (score 1):

You can do this without any pivot statement at all.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

df_wider0 <- df %>%
            mutate(result0 = result[match(drug, unique(drug))]) %>%
            filter(cond != 0) 
  
df_wider0

#  drug cond result result0
#1    A    1      2       1
#2    A    2      3       1
#3    B    1      4       2
#4    B    2      6       2
#5    C    1      6       3
#6    C    2      9       3
```

Plot the data :

```
ggplot(df_wider0, aes(x = result0, y = result, label = drug)) +
  geom_label() +
  facet_wrap("cond")
```

[image]